# Creating a swift File specially for VC Functions

Tags: ios, swift, class, singleton, instance

My current VC has multiple lines of code. It has multiple functions that I would like to put in a separate file. Each function uses parse data fetching...

My VC currently has this example function that is called in ViewDidLoad with various arrays. As you can see there are various arrays and strings called upon from my VC:

```
   // My View Controller //
    func getData() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: "Bar")
    query.order(byAscending: "Priority")
    query.whereKey("College", equalTo: college)
    query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
    if let objects = objects {
        for object in objects {
                if error == nil {
                    if object["Bar"] != nil && object ["Deal"] != nil && object["DealType"] != nil && object["Rank"] != nil && object["BarImage"] != nil {
                self.ArraySelected.append(object["Bar"] as! String)
                self.dealArray.append(object["Deal"] as! String)
                self.dealTypeArray.append(object["DealType"] as! String)
                self.barRankArray.append(object["Rank"] as! String)
                let barImageFile = object["BarImage"] as? PFFileObject
                let barUrlString = barImageFile?.url as! String
                            if let url = URL(string: barUrlString) {
                                let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                                if let imageData = data {
                                    self.barUrlArray.append(barUrlString as NSString)
                                    self.barImageCache.setObject(UIImage(data:imageData)!, forKey: barUrlString as NSString)
                                    self.barImageDataArray.append(imageData)
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        print(self.ArraySelected)
        self.barDisplayedTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}
```

My steps were to create a class which would hold all of functions like so. I also create an instance of my VC.  I also make the class of type NSObject. I am not positive this is correct:

```
  import UIKit
  import Parse
  //Not sure about this
  class ListofBarsVCActions: NSObject {
  //Not sure about this
  let sharedInstance = ListofBarsViewController()

  func getData() {

let query = PFQuery(className: "Bar")
query.order(byAscending: "Priority")
query.whereKey("College", equalTo: sharedInstance.college)
query.findObjectsInBackground(block: { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
if let objects = objects {
    for object in objects {
            if error == nil {
                if object["Bar"] != nil && object ["Deal"] != nil && object["DealType"] != nil && object["Rank"] != nil && object["BarImage"] != nil {
                    self.sharedInstance.ArraySelected.append(object["Bar"] as! String)
                    self.sharedInstance.dealArray.append(object["Deal"] as! String)
                    self.sharedInstance.dealTypeArray.append(object["DealType"] as! String)
                    self.sharedInstance.barRankArray.append(object["Rank"] as! String)
            let barImageFile = object["BarImage"] as? PFFileObject
            let barUrlString = barImageFile?.url as! String
                        if let url = URL(string: barUrlString) {
                            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
                            if let imageData = data {
                                self.sharedInstance.barUrlArray.append(barUrlString as NSString)
                                self.sharedInstance.barImageCache.setObject(UIImage(data:imageData)!, forKey: barUrlString as NSString)
                                self.sharedInstance.barImageDataArray.append(imageData)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        }

    self.sharedInstance.barDisplayedTableView.reloadData()
        }
    })
}


override init() {
      // do initial setup or establish an initial connection
  }
```

}

From there I go back to My VC and first create an instance of the class I just created. I then call the getData() func in viewdidload.

```
            //My VC//
            let ListofBarsVCInstance = ListofBarsVCActions()
            //ViewDidLoad://
            self.ListofBarsVCInstance.getData()
```

From there I get a crash. BAD ACCESSS. I know there is something wrong with my code, but I do not no the exact spot. I am a new coder and this is a big transition for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic implementation of MVC. You have a controller which can call a model and a view. Now, you can move your service calls to the model object.

```
self.view.addSubview(UILabel())
self.model.printSomething()
```

---

```
class EventsViewController: UIViewController {

    var model: EventsViewModel?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        model = EventsViewModel(self)
        model?.printSomething()
    }

}

class EventsViewModel: NSObject {
    weak private var controller: EventsViewController?

    init(_ controller: EventsViewController) {
        self.controller = controller
    }

    func printSomething() {
        print("printSomething")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @magellan if this or any answer solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. This indicates to to the wider community that you’ve found  a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer and yourself. There is no obligation to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to move some functions into another file for convenience, then you want an extension, not an extra object. Get rid of the sharedInstance and instead:

```
extension ListofBarsViewController {

    ... Functions you want in this file ...

}
```

That said, wanting to do this suggests the view controller is doing too much work, and you should move more of this logic into your model classes and make the view controller simpler.

Comment: Is it more aesthetically pleasing for a coder to do this? I thought organizing my classes would make the VC thinner and easier than to sift thru vs. a VC with mult. extensions at the bottom.

Comment: The extension can be in another file if that's convenient. But to make the VC thinner, you definitely want to move the work into the model objects and out of the VC entirely, not put a wrapper around the VC. Basically the call to PFQuery should not be in a VC at all (or in anything that knows about a VC). The call to PFQuery should be in model objects, and the VC should consume the results after parsing.